# Querying the most recent records with two fields: datestamp and timestamp

Tags: postgresql, query, datetime, timestamp

I have a table called airquality that has records for air quality measurements taken on different days and times within those days. These date/timestamps are stored in two different columns: validdate and validtime. I can query either one of those fields to return me the maximum value with the following query:

```
select * 
from airquality
where validdate = (select max(validdate) from airquality)
```

This returns me the correct rows for the most recent day (format: `05/02/20`). But how can I modify this query to also check for the latest time in the validtime column (format: `16:00`)?

I tried the following:

```
select * 
from airquality
where validdate = (select max(validdate) from airquality)
and validtime = (select max(validtime) from airquality)
```

But this doesn't work because I can have timestamps for 05/01/2020 that have a timestamp that 05/02/2020 doesn't have yet. (Example: 05/02/20 16:00 vs 05/01/20 23:00)

I am on Postgres 12.2

Any suggestions or ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compose a proper timestamp out of the two, like `timestamp '2010-12-12' + time '10:30'

Comment: What was the reason for not storing these as one timestamp?

Comment: The csv I was using to insert rows to the db has them as separate rows. I could just add the code in my python script to combine them, but I was seeing if there was a workaround. And a_horse_with_no_name provided the answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a proper timestamp from the two columns:

```
select * 
from airquality
where validdate + validtime  = (select max(validdate + validtime ) from airquality)
```

This assumes that `validdate` is corrected defined with the data type `date` and `validtime` is correct defined as a `time` column.

Comment: Great solution that doesn't require that I create a new column that concatenates date and time.